# Upgrading Plone 4017 to 4018

Tags: plone

I really need some help with Plone. I am experiencing some issue upgrading from 4017 to 4018.
All the Plone websites say "The site configuration is outdated and needs to be upgraded."

When I press Upgrade I get the following error:

"Starting the migration from version: 4017
End of upgrade path, migration has finished
The upgrade path did NOT reach current version
Migration has failed"

I was really hoping someone could help me sort out this issue and also help me get to the latest stable build of Plone 4.1.

Thanks.

Comment: There should be some more info or even a traceback printed on that same page, or a link to the error log. Please provide that information.

Comment: @maurits: no, in this case there is no traceback, as it is not an error message generated from a traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when there is a discrepancy between the current Plone setup profile version number and the upgrade steps final version number. Because there is no step from 4017 to 4018 you get this error message.

This is not necessarily a problem. Your upgrade to version 4017 worked without a hitch. What exact Plone version are you upgrading to, 4.0.9? It may be worth reporting this as a (low priority) bug, but I doubt there is anything there to prevent you from using your site.

To illustrate, I see this all the time when using the latest development version of the `Products.CMFPlone` package, because that'll be one version 'tick' further than the latest release of the `plone.app.upgrade` package can upgrade me to.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Plone and the organisation I am a intern at use it. I do not know what version I am upgrading to It basically said "The site configuration is outdated and needs to be upgraded." so I click on it and presses Upgrade. I was assuming it would be 4.1. 

The websites work but I really need to upgrade/update it and make sure upgrades work for the future. Also where can I get traceback/log from?

Comment: @bil: there is no traceback, and your upgrade is otherwise fine. Go to your control panel ("Site setup", URL ends with `/@@overview-controlpanel`) you'll see the version info at the bottom.

Comment: Hi, okey. How can I get rid of "The site configuration is outdated and needs to be upgraded. Please continue with the upgrade." message , or atleast how can I upgrade to 4018 or 4.0.1? I need to get it done as my boss wants it to be done but I keep running into error above.

Version Overview
 * Plone 4.0.5
 * Zope 2.12.13
 * Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Dec 22 2010, 13:42:14) [GCC 4.4.3]

Comment: So install 4.1, and there will be a real upgrade.

Comment: How do I install 4.1 without loosing the current configuration changes and content?

Comment: @bil: You can safely upgrade to Plone 4.0.9, which should certainly resolve this issue for you. An upgrade to 4.1.x should be relatively simple and easy too, existing configuration and content generally is upgraded along. Follow the [Plone Upgrade Guide](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide) when upgrading to 4.1.

Comment: How do I do upgrade to 4.0.9 then please, I do not seem to be understanding how to upgrade . Thanks

Comment: Look for your buildout.cfg configuration file. Does it have an 'extends' line in there pointing to a particular Plone version? If so, update the version number there and run "bin/buildout" to update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, no there is no line in extends pointing to a Plone version, it just says versions.cfg.

Comment: Right, then versions.cfg is a downloaded and locally stored version; it'll have a comment at the top as to which version it covers. You should be able to replace either the `extends = versions.cfg` line with a `extends = http://dist.plone.org/release/4.0.9/versions.cfg` line, or replace the contents of `versions.cfg` with the contents of the file at that URL.

Comment: Martijn Thanks for your reply. When I put the link pretty much nothing happens apart from it saying what is Required. When I replace versions.cfg with the contents from the link I get the following errors

pastie.org/2631784

Comment: @bil: Upgrade `distribute`: http://readthedocs.org/docs/collective-docs/en/latest/troubleshooting/buildout.html#versionconflict-distribute-0-6-19

Comment: @bil: I think we are now going way beyond the scope of this question and StackOverflow's strengths. Maybe you can come to the [Plone IRC channel](http://plone.org/support/chat) to see if someone can help you troubleshoot this.

Comment: Hi, I have already been their and was not able to resolve much and was told to reinstall Plone and migrate to the new installation. Your help has been much appreciated though.

Comment: @bil: NP. Reinstall and migrate might actually be an easier option in your case; just move the var directory over. :-)

Comment: I am starting to believe that you are right and it probably will be easier. :) Thanks.